Kaplan Meier Curve: Inconsistency in the number of rows of the data provided to the ggsurvplot function."
I want to do a Kaplan meier curve. But i have this error. in my data I don't have NA for my time and event variable. I don't understand. Please help me:
ggsurvplot(
    Km_fit1, data=DF, risk.table = TRUE, 
    conf.int = TRUE, + ggtheme = theme_minimal())


Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 0, 64

I try to clean my dataframe and repeat the process. It's the same thing

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete code example and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.
